# how to rename python script to be used in lambda - lambda_handler vs main() function name?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

initially this was python script on ec2 but now i want it become aws lambda - generated from terraform! Since aws lambda needs lambda_handler function vs "__ main __".

I wonder what to put in my tf code for handler arg.

The python script(it gets zipped by terraform then loaded up to aws lambda):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import json
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

queue = boto3.resource(
    'sqs', region_name='us-east-1').get_queue_by_name(QueueName="erjan")
table = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1').Table('Votes')

def process_message(message):
    try:
        payload = message.message_attributes
        voter = payload['voter']['StringValue']
        vote = payload['vote']['StringValue']
        logging.info("Voter: %s, Vote: %s", voter, vote)
        update_count(vote)
        message.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print('-----EXCEPTION-----')


def update_count(vote):
    logging.info('update count....')
    cur_count = 0
    if vote == 'b':
        response = table.get_item(Key={'voter': 'count'})
        item = response['Item']
        item['b'] += 1
        table.put_item(Item=item)

    elif vote == 'a':
        table.update_item(
            Key={'voter': 'count'},
            UpdateExpression="ADD a :incr",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': 1})


if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.info('--------inside main-------')

    while True:
        try:
            messages = queue.receive_messages(MessageAttributeNames=['vote', 'voter'])
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logging.info("Stopping...")
            break
        except:
            logging.error(sys.exc_info()[0])
            continue
        for message in messages:
            process_message(message)
```

the tf code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "vote_processor_lambda_iam_role" {
  name               = "vote_processor_lambda_iam_role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Sid": ""
            }
        ]
    }
    EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "vote_processor_dynamodb_policy" {

  name   = "vote_processor_dynamodb_policy"
  policy = <<EOF
    {
    "some json"
}
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_vote_processor_dynamodb_policy_to_iam_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.vote_processor_lambda_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.vote_processor_dynamodb_policy.arn
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "vote_processor_sqs_policy" {

 name   = "vote_processor_sqs_policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "some json"
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "vote_processor_sqs_access_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.vote_processor_lambda_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.vote_processor_sqs_policy.arn
}



data "archive_file" "vote_processor_zip_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/vote_processor.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/vote_processor.zip"
}



#what to put in handler arg? 

resource "aws_lambda_function" "vote_processor_lambda_backend" {
  filename      = "${path.module}/vote_processor.zip"
  function_name = "vote_processor"
  role          = aws_iam_role.vote_processor_lambda_iam_role.arn
  handler       = "result.lambda_handler"   #should this be __main__?
  runtime       = "python3.9"

}
```

should i rename the python script **main** function be "lambda handler"? or vice versa in tf code?

Comment: No need to rename the file, but a lambda needs a lambda handler as a starting point. This handler takes an event and and a context. Inside this handler you can call your main or other code.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Answer (score 2):

"__ main __" is not necessary. The following syntax defines lambda functions.

[Lambda function handler in Python - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

> You can use the following general syntax when creating a function handler in Python:
>
> ```
> def handler_name(event, context): 
>     ...
>     return some_value
> ```

The handler to be set for the tf is as follows.

[Lambda function handler in Python - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

> The Lambda function handler name specified at the time that you create a Lambda function is derived from:
>
> The name of the file in which the Lambda handler function is located.
>
> The name of the Python handler function.
>
> A function handler can be any name; however, the default name in the Lambda console is lambda_function.lambda_handler. This function handler name reflects the function name (lambda_handler) and the file where the handler code is stored (lambda_function.py).